# PHP script to alter multiple databases

Tags: php, database

i just want to know if exists a php script where i

1 - setup a mysql connection ( host,user,password )

2 - visually select databases i want to alter

3 - set sql statements ( from .sql file or text on web form )

4 - execute specified sql statements on all selected databases

**problem to solve** :: i have +100 databases with same structure on same server, executing a simple "ALTER TABLE" on each database is a boring / time-loss task, iam currently doing this manually with phpMyAdmin, but i know exists a better way.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is a very intuitive tool.

Comment: @JanL, check updated question please c:

Comment: @Nanne, name or link please ?? n.n

Comment: cant you just write some php which takes a list of all the databases and runs a loop threw them making the change?

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard, yea! i can do that, thats what i want, but, i think MAYBE that scripts already exists...

Comment: I am sorry, but if you are not able to write a script to archive such a trivial task, then you should really learn a bit more of php.

Comment: @JanL i can do it, but i prefer know if a code for this "trivial task" exists instead of star coding something already existing... thats the magic of the programming.

i dont think this is a "trivial task" when 20 minutes or more are required to do this "manually".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what pre-fab script could exist, but you are looking at a one-shot thing, are you not? Why not just write a script?

It would look something like this (pseudo code)

```
$yourDatabases = array($database1, $databas2, ....);

foreach($yourDatabases as $database){
    connect($database);
    query("your alter table");
    close($database);
}
```

Comment: yea, i can do that, but if a professional script already exists, i want to test him n_n

Comment: I don't think you are going to find "a professional script". Maybe there are mysql clients that can do this, but if you are looking for a script you get this. You are aware that there are other methods to connect (like for instance Workbench), aside from scripts? Did you do any research into them?

Comment: you could use transactions before making the changes and roll back if needed (however my knowledge in this area is a bit limited)

Comment: Yes, but transactions between multiple databases is a bit tricky. You could open a transaction for each connection, open all connections, start all transactions, do all alter tables, and if they work, commit all transactions, but that seems a bit over the top for a "simple alter table".

Comment: +1. writing your own script for this rather special but not complex case will be way less time consuming than hunting for and testing an existing script

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the `phpmyadmin`

Comment: in fact, i realize this job using phpMyAdmin but when i have 100 databases with same structure, executing a simple "ALTER TABLE" on each database is a boring / time-loss task .-.